# How to avoid duplicate events when combining GestureDetector and Listener in flutter

Tags: flutter

In the example below we have a tappable red container inside a green container.

- The red container is wrapped with Listener
- The green container is wrapped with GestureDetector

Problem: when tapping the red container, BOTH the Listener and GestureDetector receive events, which is a mistake. (Only the topmost widget should get a tap event, when tapped. And only the green widget should get an event when tapped). If both wrapped with GestureDetector, only the topmost widget gets the event.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(children: [
          // Parent-child -- two events when red is tapped
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("Green");
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 100.0,
              height: 100.0,
              child: Center(
                child: Listener(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                  onPointerDown: (_) {
                    print("Red");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as an option wrap `Listener` with `GestureDetector` to prevent event bubbling

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(children: [
              // Parent-child -- two events when red is tapped
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print("Green");
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                      onTap: (){},
                      child: Listener(
                        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                        onPointerDown: (_) {
                          print("Red");
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          width: 50.0,
                          height: 50.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are special types of widgets which can do this thing easily.

```
 AbsorbPointer 
 IgnorePointer
```

Try this widget it will make your solution easy

Comment: Thanks. I also though AbsorbPointer might work for this purpose. It does not. Neither does IgnorePointer.

Comment: I tried all possible ways with `Listener` but failed. specify what kind of user experience do you want. Maybe there is no solution with `Listener`. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Stack can solve this problem:

```
Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print('green');
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                ),
              ),
              Listener(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onPointerDown: (_) {
                  print("Red");
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 50.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

,

Comment: Unfortunately, in complex UIs we can't implement all the widgets as a single stack

Answer (score 0):

If you want only a click event in both `green` and `red` separately than you can wrap your `red` `Container()` into a `InkWell()` widget.

See bellow code example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // Parent-child -- two events when red is tapped
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print("Green");
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: (){
                        print('red');
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        width: 50.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- that's not what the question is about.